# Minecraft "power ripple"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Does there exist any known way to create a "power ripple" using redstone; i.e. a situation that is, essentially, just like a sequence of wire-repeater segments, but powering every intermediate block, rather than, as is the theoretical maximum for wire-repeater, every second block?

**Edit:**

To explain more fully: When a stretch of redstone is activated it is enabled all at once, with no delay between the first and the last piece of wire; repeater-laden wire, on the other hand, has a delay. Unfortunately, repeater-laden wire has "blind spots" when it comes to providing power.

Is there any way to create wiring that has a ripple effect, but that gives power to every block along the way?

**Reedit:**

I keep forgetting this; but people can't read my mind over the internet. :P The reason for this question turning up in the first place is that I need it for moderately temporary situations.

**Rereedit:**

End result of all the work:

Comment: May just be me but I am not sure what you are trying to ask here. Could you be more explicit in your example?

Comment: I think I understand your question, but what do you mean by "blind spots"? Perhaps you could explain the context you are going to use this circuit in, because I don't quite know why repeaters would interfere with what you're trying to build. I suppose you could have a wire on the surface, and have Redstone Torches below it, delayed via Repeaters, causing the signal through the wire to slowly progress. *(I'm not sure if this is what you want, so I'm posting this as a comment)*

Comment: Dang, @Kevin Y, take a risk, post as an *answer* - not like you're worried about the karma, after all :)

Comment: I'm away from a computer at the moment, but I'll get an answer with screenshots posted with what I believe the answer to your question is, @Williham, as soon as possible.

Comment: @Williham, so which is the best answer? (pretty sure it's not mine :) And what were you actually trying to do? Send a delayed pulse, or just avoid blind spots?

Comment: @Cyclops: Well, it certainly isn't yours, that's for sure. ;) But seriously, tho', I'm torn between my own answer and @KevinY's.

Comment: Ahh, that's what you were doing. I wasn't quite sure what context you were using the circuit in, so I guess my solution doesn't work too great for your situation. Cool invention!

Comment: @KevinY: Thanks. I'm presently (unsuccessfully) trying to make a vertical version.

Comment: Agreed it's a very cool application of pistons. I'm fairly sure making a *vertical* version will be impossible, or at least hugely more difficult. Good luck. :)

Comment: @Cyclops: Theoretically, a vertical version should be identical. In practice, however, some quirk of how vertical pistons work cause them to jam when arranged vertically in a similar arrangement.

Comment: @Williham, identical? What about *gravity*? :) In the horizontal one, the machine is moving over ground, but turn it vertical, and it's going *up* off the ground. There may be a way to do it, but I don't think turning the original machine on its side will do it. :)

Comment: @Cyclops: Whatcho talkin' about? Ain't no gravity in MC, foo'! I've done extensive testing by turning this particular machine on its side, and I'm fairly confident that some quirk of vertical pistons is preventing it from working. Don't make me make another video to prove it. :p

Comment: @Cyclops @Williham Totland - a vertical version is possible - like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cix161oQWGA

Comment: @tombull89: Interesting sollution; adding ladders between the push/pull units. That might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tooling about for a bit I came up with my own method; it's similar to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25633/minecraft-power-ripple/25642#25642), but with somewhat quicker setup:

[image]

(Note that this is designed to power the blocks in a trench between the two lines.)

Comment: It seems to me that the repeaters should be set to 2 ticks (rather than 1 as shown), with the lines having a 1-tick delay relative to each other.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, here is a way of creating a "power ripple". Think of the sandstone blocks above-ground as ground level; I built it this way so it's easier to see. The circuitry would be underground.

Repeaters have an interesting property of being able to "power" blocks, causing the blocks to give power. Each Repeater in this image is powering the sandstone block in front, turning the Redstone Torch on top of them off, and is also powering the next Repeater.

[image]

When this button is pressed, the Redstone Torch turns off, causing the chain of Repeaters to slowly turn off, which also causes the Redstone Torches underneath to slowly turn on, in order.

[image]

The result is the line of Redstone Dust on the surface gradually turns on, and then gradually turns off.

[image]

Comment: This is nice for permanent installations, but it does carry a bit of overhead. Will it work as expected with the two lines offset by one meter?

Comment: I probably shouldn't of put two different lines in my screenshots, but basically, I just had the signal to wrap around to see how "ripply" the signal was. And assuming by `offset by one meter` you're wondering if you could build multiple lines parallel to each other with one block in between each, then yes, it should.

Comment: Accepting my own answer, as it is what I ended up going with; but I do like your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your goal is to power a row of closely spaced redstone-activated devices.

Any solution is going to involve:

1. some kind of alternating repeaters and redstone, because you need to insulate the adjacent wiring;
2. multiple layers to make the connections.

The below is the first solution I came up with; there's probably a more efficient one. All of the repeaters are at delay 1 except for the bottom row (delay 2) and the middle row of the upper section (delay 3). The input comes in from the bottom right (the wire you see goes to a switch I used to watch the pistons). I've verified that when connected to a row of pistons, this triggers them all at distinct evenly-spaced times.

[image: image of solution]

If you want to power blocks from below, then a similar scheme ending in vertical redstone torches rather than repeaters can probably be used.

Comment: Well, d'oh! The answers using a pair of repeater lines out of phase are much better all around.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a bit of, erm, overkill, maybe? ;) Still, looks like it gives very fine-tuned control, and might be useful in other situations, so +1.